# Replace arithmetic expression with printf of expression arguments

Tags: c, text, sed, awk

I was working with a polyhedral compiler that produce quite unreadable code, here is a small sample:

```
for (t2=2*t1;t2<=min(floord(2*T+N-3,32),floord(64*t1+N+61,32));t2++) {
  for (t3=max(ceild(32*t2-N-27,32),2*t1);t3<=min(min(floord(2*T+N-3,32),floord(64*t1+N+61,32)),floord(32*t2+N+27,32));t3++) {
    if ((t1 <= floord(32*t3-N+1,64)) && (t2 <= t3-1)) {
      if ((N+1)%2 == 0) {
        for (t5=max(32*t2,32*t3-N+4);t5<=32*t2+31;t5++) {
          a[-32*t3+t5+N-2][N-2]=b[-32*t3+t5+N-2][N-2];;
        }
      }
    }
    if ((t1 <= floord(32*t2-N+1,64)) && (t2 >= t3)) {
      if ((N+1)%2 == 0) {
        for (t6=max(32*t3,32*t2-N+4);t6<=min(32*t2,32*t3+31);t6++) {
          a[N-2][-32*t2+t6+N-2]=b[N-2][-32*t2+t6+N-2];;
        }
      }
    }
```

I was trying to debug a part of the compiler by translating arithmetic expression in the produced code with a printf of the array indices, e.g., this expression:

```
a[-32*t3+t5+N-2][N-2]=b[-32*t3+t5+N-2][N-2];;
```

should become this printf:

```
printf("a[%d][%d] = b[%d][%d]\n",-32*t3+t5+N-2,N-2,-32*t3+t5+N-2,N-2);
```

I started trying with awk and produced this simple program that identifies strings to be modified and let the rest of the program unchanged:

```
awk '{if ($0 ~ "^[ ]*[a,b]") print "printf("; else print $0;}'
```

However, I do not know how to parse the arithmetic expression in order to leave its structure while removing the indexes of the array accesses.
I tried with a while loop but I am stuck at the moment.
awk should be ok to do such substitions but any suggestions in other languages are welcome!

**update** The arithmetic expression can be any arithmetic expression, such as:

```
b[t3][t4]=0.2*(a[t3][t4]+a[t3][t4-1]+a[t3][1+t4]+a[1+t3][t4]+a[t3-1][t4]);;
```

Comment: Could you outline how the 'arithmetic expressions' can look? Is it always `a[smth][smth]=b[smth][smth];;` or ...?

Comment: it is a generic arithmetic expressions, I unluckily cut and paste a piece of code that had 2 similar statements. (update)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code:**

```
awk '/\[/ { \
    sub(/^ */, ""); \
    sub(/;*$/, ""); \
    print \
        "printf(\"" \
        gensub("\\[[^]]*\\]", "[%d]", "g") \
        "\"" \
        gensub("[^\\[]*\\[([^]]*)\\][^\\[]*", ",\\1", "g") \
        ");" \
    ; \
    next; \
}1'
```

**Explanations:**

- `awk '/\[/ { ........; next; }1'` will execute `........` on any line where it finds a `[` character, and will print the line untouched otherwise.
- `sub(/^ */, "");` trims leading space characters off the current line
- `sub(/;*$/, "");` trims tailing semi-colon characters off the current line
- This is followed by a `print` statement concatenating 5 bits
- `gensub("\\[[^]]*\\]", "[%d]", "g")` returns a copy of the current line, where any square-bracketed statements are replaced with with `[%d]`. Note that nested square-brackets would break this. Also note, that as opposed to `sub`, the `gensub` command does not actually modify the current line.
- `gensub("[^\\[]*\\[([^]]*)\\][^\\[]*", ",\\1", "g")` also takes a copy of the current line, and for each square-bracketed expression it finds, it does 3 things:

  - `[^\\[]*` removes leading non-`[` characters
  - `\\[([^]]*)\\]` matches the square-bracketed expression, and `",\\1"` replaces it with a comma character followed by what was inside the square-brackets
  - `[^\\[]*` removes trailing non-`[` characters (until the next square-bracketed expression or the end of the line)
- Note that removing both leading and trailing non-`[` characters is redundant between 2 square-bracketed expression, but is useful at the very beginning and the very end of the line.

**Input:**

```
for (t2=2*t1;t2<=min(floord(2*T+N-3,32),floord(64*t1+N+61,32));t2++) {
  for (t3=max(ceild(32*t2-N-27,32),2*t1);t3<=min(min(floord(2*T+N-3,32),floord(64*t1+N+61,32)),floord(32*t2+N+27,32));t3++) {
    if ((t1 <= floord(32*t3-N+1,64)) && (t2 <= t3-1)) {
      if ((N+1)%2 == 0) {
        for (t5=max(32*t2,32*t3-N+4);t5<=32*t2+31;t5++) {
          a[-32*t3+t5+N-2][N-2]=b[-32*t3+t5+N-2][N-2];;
        }
      }
    }
    if ((t1 <= floord(32*t2-N+1,64)) && (t2 >= t3)) {
      if ((N+1)%2 == 0) {
        for (t6=max(32*t3,32*t2-N+4);t6<=min(32*t2,32*t3+31);t6++) {
          a[N-2][-32*t2+t6+N-2]=b[N-2][-32*t2+t6+N-2];;
        }
      }
    }


    b[t3][t4]=0.2*(a[t3][t4]+a[t3][t4-1]+a[t3][1+t4]+a[1+t3][t4]+a[t3-1][t4]);;
```

**Output:**

```
for (t2=2*t1;t2<=min(floord(2*T+N-3,32),floord(64*t1+N+61,32));t2++) {
  for (t3=max(ceild(32*t2-N-27,32),2*t1);t3<=min(min(floord(2*T+N-3,32),floord(64*t1+N+61,32)),floord(32*t2+N+27,32));t3++) {
    if ((t1 <= floord(32*t3-N+1,64)) && (t2 <= t3-1)) {
      if ((N+1)%2 == 0) {
        for (t5=max(32*t2,32*t3-N+4);t5<=32*t2+31;t5++) {
printf("a[%d][%d]=b[%d][%d]",-32*t3+t5+N-2,N-2,-32*t3+t5+N-2,N-2);
        }
      }
    }
    if ((t1 <= floord(32*t2-N+1,64)) && (t2 >= t3)) {
      if ((N+1)%2 == 0) {
        for (t6=max(32*t3,32*t2-N+4);t6<=min(32*t2,32*t3+31);t6++) {
printf("a[%d][%d]=b[%d][%d]",N-2,-32*t2+t6+N-2,N-2,-32*t2+t6+N-2);
        }
      }
    }

printf("b[%d][%d]=0.2*(a[%d][%d]+a[%d][%d]+a[%d][%d]+a[%d][%d]+a[%d][%d])",t3,t4,t3,t4,t3,t4-1,t3,1+t4,1+t3,t4,t3-1,t4);
```

Answer (score 1):

To split the expression:

```
a[N-2][-32*t2+t6+N-2]=b[N-2][-32*t2+t6+N-2];
```

into an array, use split:

```
split( $0, ar, "[][]" )
```

After this call, `ar[2] = "N-2"`, `ar[4] = "-32*t2+t6+N-2"`, etc.  The regex in split looks a little odd, but basically it is just splitting on either `[` or `]`.  Obviously, this is pretty fragile and a complete parser would be best, but this should help.